# Is there a way to tell what forces IE 11 compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

There is a number of ways to force compatibility mode in IE 11: using HTTP response headers on web server, special tags in web page template, using group policies/Enterprise Compatibility mode. Is there a sure way to tell what exactly forces compatibility mode for specific page when looking at the client side only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the F12 developer tools. They should be able to tell you what's going on in the background.
[image]

Comment: Fantastic, in addition to HTML1203 there also can be "HTML1122: Internet Explorer is running in Enterprise Mode emulating IE8"... Is there complete list of this type of HTMLxxxx messages related with compatibility modes available anywhere?

Comment: @Mikhail this page seems to list many, if not all, the HTML codes for IE. [Console error messages in F12 developer tools (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn423949(v=vs.85).aspx)